# Выполнение внешних команд с помощью exec в php

Tags: php, linux

Как можно проверить отработала ли команда или нет,выполняю архивацию файла в ответе приходит постоянно 0,не понятно что за ответ такой и как его проверять успешно ли выполнилась архивация или нет. `$output` вообще всегда содержит пустой массив. Или `0` означает что нет ошибок?

```
exec('tar -czvf archive.tar.gz '.$archivePath, $output, $response);

echo $response;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Когда все успешно завершено приходит ноль, поэтому делаем проверку ниже:

```
  <?php
    exec('tar -czvf archive.tar.gz '.$archivePath, $output, $response);

    // Если не ноль, то есть ошибка
    if (!$response) {
        echo "Created Successfully";
    } else {
        echo "not created";
    }
  ?>
```

Comment: Спасибо я так и понял что 0 это означает что нет ошибок.Вот сейчас указал неверный путь и вернул 2,то есть 2 ошибки

Comment: все правельно :)

Answer (score 4):

Да, нулевой (0) статус завершения внешней программы это завершение без ошибок. Но нужно понимать что цифра обозначает не количество ошибок, а её тип.

В зависимости от системы можно ознакомится с кодами выхода для [Windons](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681381(v=vs.85).aspx) и [Linux](http://www-numi.fnal.gov/offline_software/srt_public_context/WebDocs/Errors/unix_system_errors.html).

Comment: Спасибо ознакомлюсь